# How Hanumanji visited Patal loka?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, lokas

In one version of Ramayana, Lord Hanuman visited Patala loka to save Lord Rama. But how did he find way to Patal loka?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The story is told in the Krittivasi Ramayana, a Bengali version of the epic.  To protect Rama and Lakshmana from Ravana's son Mahiravana, Hanuman makes a fortress out of his tail and puts them inside, with the top of the fortress being guarded by Vishnu's Sudarshana Chakra.  Vibhishana tells Hanuman not to let anyone in, not even his own father, because Mahiravana can disguise himself as anyone.  But then Mahiravana disguises himself as Vibhishana, and Hanuman lets him in.  After some time Hanuman realizes that wasn't Vibhishana, and so Hanuman and the real Vibhishana [go into the fortress](http://www.new1.dli.ernet.in/data9/upload/0288/185/PTIFF/00000402.tif)

> "I am filled with dread.  Has Mahiravana with his magic gone within the fortress?" thought Hanuman as he bowed his head in shame....  "Listen Vibhishana," Hanuman said, "let us go within to see Rama and Lakshmana." "Let us go," said Vibhishana.  Both of them rushed in and to their surprise they saw a tunnel which was not there before.

Then Hanuman [goes into the tunnel](http://www.new1.dli.ernet.in/data9/upload/0288/185/PTIFF/00000406.tif):

> Then he wept aloud "Alas! When shall I see Rama and Lakshmana? Remain together all of you in one place till I return." Bowing to Sugriva he took his leave and entering the tunnel, was lost to sight.  Inside the tunnel he went on and on, till he came to the Under Earth World.  Here he found a sunny land, with flowing rivers and beautifully designed palaces and most lovely women.  He saw holy men in their forest retreats busy with their sacred books and prayers.  He went further and met many kinds of people, some had four hands, and there was no sickness nor sorrow, old age nor death.  Many amazing countries he passed through but could not find any trace of Rama and Lakshmana. One by one, he searched every house until he came to the palace of Mahiravana.

What happens after that is well-known.  Mahiravana wants to sacrifice Rama and Lakshmana to the goddess Kali, and tells them to bow to the Kali statue.  They say they're not accustomed to bowing, so Mahiravana shows them how to do it and Hanuman takes the opportunity to cut off Mahiravana's heads.  He then fights off Mahiravana's wife and son Ahiravana, and then Rama, Lakshmana, and Hanuman leave Patalaloka.

Note that this story is not mentioned at all in the Valmiki Ramayana, only in much later versions.

Comment: Also before leaving Rama crowned the Magardhwaj(son of Hanuman ) the king of patal poori

Comment: @jaysheelutekar Makardhwaja is not mentioned in the Valmiki Ramayan, and he's not even mentioned in the Krittivasi Ramayana I quoted in my answer.  He's only mentioned in later versions of the Ramayana, like the Orissa version of the Ramayana; see this journal paper: http://www.indologica.com/volumes/vol10/vol10_art19_smith.pdf

Comment: Whoever wrote this Krittivasi Ramayana isn't even aware of the fact that Patala or any other loka is not located inside Earth. Even TV serials show this.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, it's not a unique problem with Krittivas (author of the Krittivasi Ramayana).  There are plenty of Hindu scriptures that discuss people going to Patalaloka by digging within the Earth.  So your problem is with Hindu scripture, not with Krittivas.  In any case, I agree with you that Lokas are in separate Universes.  Perhaps if you dig within the earth you can then use some spiritual power to transport yourself to Patalaloka.

Comment: Do you have links of Krittivasi Ramayana? Links you have given are not working.